# Windows Remote Desktop logging

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 machine that several folks Remote Desktop into.  I'm looking for a way to log who (IP address) has logged in locally (on the machine that has been logged into) and/or if there is a snazzy way to email myself a notification whenever someone logs in that would be even better.

Is this just a matter of port listening?  Can Windows do this on it's on without third party tools?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in functionality for this, but there are definitely Win32 API calls you can use to do this -- what language are you using or familiar with?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the end solution but in the interim you could create a shell or batch script that executes at log in and sends an email.  The other option is tapping into the EventLogs.  Perhaps you can email something form the event log.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771314.aspx

http://www.petri.co.il/send_mail_from_script.htm

Good luck.

Comment: ooo triggering on logon!  that didn't even occur to me.  that could suffice as a simple solution.... just have to track down the IP some how.  good thought.

Comment: I really don't know how to get the IP without using the EventLog.  Even then, I don't know for sure that even provides it.  I don't have a way to test for it at the moment.  Please respond if you figure that one out.  Cheers!

Comment: you could use netstat -f | find "3389" to get ip, 3389 is default remote desktop port.